# Convert text or number to date in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there any way that i can convert text or number to a date?

for example :
20201104 → 2020/11/04

Comment: Hi,
that depends on what you want to do. Do you want to display this text string as a date? Do you need to write it to a data extension time field? Please also share what attempts you have made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak thanks for the comment!
I would like to display it on the email content. the text value is from data extension field value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of string like `20201104` the [DateParse()](https://ampscript.guide/dateparse/) function will not be able to directly convert this string and use the FormatDate() function.

So your only option is to divide the string into parts using [Substring()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) and stitch them back together using [Concat()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) to recreate the formatting you need.

Steps:

1. Create variables extracting the 3 date parts you need, for example get the month by using `Substring(@yourDateString, 5, 2)` (the month starts as the 5th character of your string and you need to extract 2 characters to get the value)
2. Connect the parts together as you want using the [Concat()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) function like this: `Concat(@year, '/', @month, '/', @day)`